# Legitimate if condition skipping in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

In my code, there is an if condition, which should be passed but is skipping for some reason. It looks like this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email',None) #<-- abc@domain.com
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username) 
        user_email = user.email                #<-- u''
        if user_email is None or '' and email is not None:
                user.email = email
```

The second if condition is skipping even though it's correct(user_email is empty string and email is not None). What am I doing wrong? I also tried splitting condition in two steps but it is still skipping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
if user_email is None or ''
```

You mean

```
if user_email in [None, '']
```

You cannot include multiple values with `or` after `is`, or anywhere else, actually, English and Python (and pretty much every other programming language) are different in this regard. Your code basically evaluates to

```
if (user_email is None) or ('' == True)
```

which of course doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 if user_email is None or user_email is '' and email is not None:
            user.email = email
```

I think you might not be getting the if working correctly because you need to repeat **user_mail is ''** after the or.